# Where is origin point when OnRender is called? (0, 0) or (1,1)?

Tags: c#, wpf, custom-controls

I have some code that behaves weirdly. In a main window, there is a green `Border` that contains a custom control `MyControl` that draws its edge(left:0, top:0, right:`ActualWidth - 1`, bottom:`ActualHeight - 1`) using red brush. However, when program runs, the left and top edge of `MyControl` overlap with the left and top edge of `Border`, and there is a one-pixel-width gap between right edge of `MyControl` and right edge of `Border`, there is also another one-pixel-width gap between bottom edge of `MyControl` and bottom edge of `Border`. It seems that (1,1) instead of (0,0) is treated as origin point so X=1 is left edge, Y=1 is top edge, X=ActualWidth is right edge, Y=ActualHeight is bottom. I'm confused. Is there any wrong with my code?
Here is the code:

MyControl:

```
public class MyControl : Control
{
    protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
    {
        base.OnRender(drawingContext);
        Pen pen = new Pen(Brushes.Red, 1);
        drawingContext.DrawLine(pen, new Point(0, 0), new Point(ActualWidth - 1, 0));
        drawingContext.DrawLine(pen, new Point(0, 0), new Point(0, ActualHeight - 1));
        drawingContext.DrawLine(pen, new Point(ActualWidth - 1, 0), new Point(ActualWidth - 1, ActualHeight - 1));
        drawingContext.DrawLine(pen, new Point(0, ActualHeight - 1), new Point(ActualWidth - 1, ActualHeight - 1));
        Console.WriteLine($"{ActualWidth}, {ActualHeight}");
    }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfPlayGround.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xaml/behaviors"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfPlayGround"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
        RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Canvas>
        <Border Name="Border" BorderBrush="LightGreen" BorderThickness="1" Margin="36" ClipToBounds="True" >
            <local:MyControl x:Name="MyControl" Width="400" Height="300"></local:MyControl>
        </Border>
    </Canvas>
</Window>
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Be aware that view coordinates in WPF are double (i.e. floating point) values. Drawing a Line at y=0 with a thickness of 1 draws half of the line (the upper part) outside the view. To draw that line at the classical "pixels" you would have to use y=0.5 for the topmost pixel row.

Comment: So you would have to write something like `drawingContext.DrawLine(pen, new Point(0.5, 0.5), new Point(ActualWidth - 0.5, 0.5));`

Comment: @Clemens Can you explain the mechanism of offset 0.5？why using 0.5 can make code work as I expect？

Comment: Think of the pixel as small square areas in a raster. The upper left corner of the upper left pixel is at (0,0), while its center is at (0.5,0.5). If you want to draw from the center of pixel (x,y) to the center of pixel (u,v), you would draw a line from (x+0.5,y+0.5) to (u+0.5,v+0.5).